# making bootstrap 2 non responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have ran into a problem with bootstrap version 2, I can't really make the grid fixed. It still goes wild on different screen sizes. I've wrapped all my html elements in a container like so:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span5">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/90x90" >
        <h1 >
           Header
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="span4 offset3 text-right">
        <h3>City</h3>
        <p>+7 (343) 999999999</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>

<section class="container" id="anchors">
<div class="row">
<div class="span3 text-center">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150">
    <a class="anchor">Anchor</a>
</div>
<div class="span3 text-center">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150">
    <a class="anchor">Anchor</a>
</div>
<div class="span3 text-center">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150">
    <a class="anchor">Anchor</a>
</div>
<div class="span3 text-center">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/150x150">
    <a class="anchor">Anchor</a>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

And they still aren't fixed. So, how do i make it non responsive? Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't include the responsive stylesheet.

Comment: @sevenseacat i have a single boostrap.min that is compiled by default.

Comment: Well there's an easy way to fix that - don't use that stylesheet.

Comment: show us the css that you are referencing, and also the css you are using in this example `class="anchor"` is not a bootstrap class

Comment: I basically still haven't used any styles of my own on it, those are just in the markup for later use, also I don't think that not using bootstrap.css will solve my issue. I've googled more and stumbled upon customization with less, is that what I should be looking into? I have little experience, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decompress your css file and remove "MEDIA QUERIES" like:

```
// Landscape phones and down 
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }  

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }   

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop                  
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, choosing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment i understand you have a single css file.

You find the following and remove it completely :

```
@media screen and
(min-width: X px) and
(max-width: X px)

@media screen and
(min-device-width: X px) and
(max-device-width: X px)
```

You can use online tools to convert the min files to make it editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these two lines from your page to if you have them in there.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```