# How to make DIVs in Bootstrap 2.3.2. NOT break all at same width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

My questions might be very easy but I have not been able to find any such hints here or in other places on the web.

What I am trying to do is to have several Divs with content in one row (let's assume 6 for simplicity) but they should NOT all rearrange at the same browser width when scaling down.

So e.g. the example row has 6 divs at full width, when decreasing browser width they become two rows with 3 Divs each, and only with very small width the become 6 x 1 Div per row.

If have broken down the code into 2 Divs of span6 and then included 3 Divs of Span4 each but they still all reshuffle at the same time.

I am using this code (the background color is only set to clearly differentiate the divs visually)

```
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 1
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 2
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 3
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="span6">
        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 4
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 5
        </div>

        <div class="span4" style="background-color:#bbbbbb">
            Div 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks Kai

Comment: I don't know Bootstrap 2 - Can you use bootstrap 3? This would be trivial to do there: `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2">` tells it to span 12 columns at xs, 6 columns (so two columns, 6 grid units wide) at sm,  and 2 columns (so 6 columns, each 2 grid units wide) at md and larger.

Comment: You should take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17938884/2454790